# Update Apache Authentication Module by replacing .so file

Tags: linux, apache, module

can I update an Apache authorization module by replacing that modules .so file in the modules directory with a .so of the same filename? After I replace the file do I need to restart Apache or will it just take effect immediately?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to restart Apache.

There are lots of reasons that this will potentially fail and why its a bad idea; the right way to solve the problem would be to change the config to use the new file (which still needs to be built for the correct version of apache with the correct dependencies).